# show duration between two times using javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have asp.net web application with user-control having two text boxes to which i have assigned timepicker property's through java script.
i need to find duration between two time (between two text boxes) through java-script when any of the textbox value changes and set that duration value to label.
Overall,My user-control contain two text-boxes and one label. 
However i have tried but not able display duration in label.

This my javascript:---

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.timePicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
  jQuery(function() {
$("#<%=time3.ClientID %>, #<%=time4.ClientID %>").timePicker();

  // Store time used by duration.
  var oldTime = $.timePicker("#<%=time3.ClientID %>").getTime();
  // Keep the duration between the two inputs.

  $("#<%=time3.ClientID %>").change(function() {
      if ($("#<%=time4.ClientID %>").val()) { // Only update when second input has a value.

          // Calculate duration.
          var duration = ($.timePicker("#<%=time4.ClientID %>").getTime() - oldTime);
         ($.timePicker("#<%=txtTimeDiff.ClientID %>").setTime(new Date(duration)));
          var time = $.timePicker("#<%=time3.ClientID %>").getTime();
          // Calculate and update the time in the second input.
          $.timePicker("#<%=time4.ClientID %>").setTime(new Date(new Date(time.getTime() + duration)));
          oldTime = time;

      }
  });
  // Validate.
  $("#<%=time4.ClientID %>").change(function() {
      if ($.timePicker("#<%=time3.ClientID %>").getTime() > $.timePicker(this).getTime()) {
          $(this).addClass("error");
      }
      else {
          $(this).removeClass("error");
      }
  });
});
```

My controls:-----

```
<asp:TextBox ID="time3" Width="50px" Text="09:00"  runat="server" Height="19px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="time4" Width="50px" Text="09:00"  runat="server" Height="19px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="txtTimeDiff" Width="50px" Text="" runat="server" Height="18px"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Its because you do not set the different on txtTimeDiff in any point

Comment: i have set it previously also but it's not displaying value